# Is it possible to write 2 Android Activities (UIs) in single .java file ? if not Why?

Tags: java, android

i am new to android development. Up to now i was creating  each activity  in separate `.java` file say i have 2 activities `First_Activity` and `Second_Activity`, so two separate files viz.`First_Activity.java` and `Second_Activity.java`. But now i am curious to know that is it possible to write both first and second activity in single `.java` file?

If yes How?
If not Why not ?

thanking you in advance. .

when i write two activites in a single file then it showing me first activity successfully, but when i move to second activity by clicking on a button created to move to second activity, my app is crashing and showing "unfortunately appName stopped" . .
 i think, problem is that my second activity is not public when i write both activities in a single file.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: it shows me syntax error on each line: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s) .

Answer (score 4):

Yes it's possible. Because Java allows only one (root-)class per file you have to use inner classes:

```
public class ActivityWrapper {
    public static class ActivityOne extends Activity{
    }

    public static class ActivityTwo extends Activity{
    }
}
```

To add a Activity in your Manifest do:

```
<activity android:name="com.myapp.Wrapper$ActivityOne" />
```